# MLE of the parameters of a non-central chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Is there a nice and efficient way of estimating the parameters (degree of freedom and non-centrality parameter) of a non-central chi-squared distribution? The infinite summation of the pdf looks like a pain for the mle approach.

Comment: The PDF can be written using a Bessel function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Definition While it's not entirely trivial to compute, there are algorithms to achieve this. For instance, it's implemented in [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Chisquare.html) and [Stata](https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?nchi2den).

Comment: Thank you. So it seems to be brute force. Anything smart about this implementation or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Might be better to look in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are certainly many things smart in the implementation, both of the PDF, and of the MLE estimator. For the PDF, you can try looking for dnchisq.c in R source code, but it will probably be difficult to follow every detail. For estimation, try googling for "mle noncentral chi square". You can start with [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171505/r-parameter-estimates-for-non-central-chi-squared-distribution). But why do you ask? Do you want to implement this (for what kind of project?), or to use software (e.g. R) to do this?

Comment: Yes, I would like to implement it myself, because I would like to implement on top a GARCH process for the non-centrality parameter. Thanks for the link. I will have a look.

Comment: Ok, then don't try to reinvent the wheel, and by all means don't implement a special function defined as infinite series naively. There are often better approximation methods based on other approaches (possibly polynomial or rational approximation, continued fractions, etc.). Since this kind of task is not easy, it's usually better to find available source code, possibly open source (gsl, R...). Also, you may have everything at hand if you implement in R or Matlab, you will have to look for a library if you want to develop in C.

Comment: I had a look and it seems that he best way is to use the approximation of the non-central chi-2 distribution by Sankaran ("Approximations to the non-central chi-square distribution", Biometrika, 1963, vol. 50, no. 1-2, pp. 199–204,https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/50.1-2.199 ). The approximation by Ding ("Algorithm AS 275: Computing the Non-Central X2 Distribution Function", Applied Statistics, 1992, vol. 41, no. 2, pp. 478-482) does not seem to perform well for mle.

Comment: I have not tried the proxy by Benton and Krishnamoorthy ("Computing Discrete Mixtures of Continuous Distributions: Noncentral Chisquare, Noncentral t and the Distribution of the Square of the Sample Multiple Correlation Coefficient", Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 2003, vol. 43, pp. 249–267).

Answer (score 0):

It is a two parameter family and the first two moments are linear functions of $k$ and $\lambda$, so a moment match approach is a fair start.